# xpath : Get a button by type and text

Tags: button, text, xpath, types, submit

I've a web page with following template :

```
<body>
        ...
    <a type="submit"....>
    "A1"
    </a>
    <a type="submit"....>
    "A2"
    </a>
    <a type="submit"....>
    "A3"
    </a>
    <a type="submit"....>
    "A4"
    </a>
    <a type="submit"....>
    "A5"
    </a>
        ...
</body>
```

I'm finding the all set of "buttons" by next query :

```
//a[@type='submit']
```

The question is , what should I add, in order to get a spesific button, let's say "A4"

10x

Comment: If this is HTML, it is illegal HTML. `a` elements cannot legally have a `type` attribute. If you want buttons, you need to use `input` or `button` elements.

Comment: yes, that is the HTML I have, actually I've nothing to do with it cause it's third party component ... Any way to answer the question ?

Comment: Sounds like a bad third-party component to me. But I'll have a go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Presuming there are no useful attributes on the `a` elements (e.g. `class` or `id`), you can use the `contains` XPath function:

```
//a[@type='submit' and contains(., "A4")]
```

Comment: @Igal Well, it works for me when I try it. Perhaps provide your actual code? Psychic debugging is always tricky.

Comment: In my situation, I was trying to get a button inside of an existing form. Here's how I did it:
`//form[@name="some.form"]//button[contains(.,"Join")]`